# Arbitrary input parameters in http call from browser with RequestMapping and fromUriString

Tags: java, http, spring-boot

I have the following call:

```
http://localhost:8080/report?name=HelloReport&download=true
```

How can I append arbitrary input parameter at the end of the http request?

My code:

```
    ...
    @RequestMapping(value = "/report", params = {"name", "download"})
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> report(
        @RequestParam(value = "name") String name,
        @RequestParam(value = "download") boolean download) {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    if (download) {
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData("inline", name + ".pdf");
    }
    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

    //MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(request.getRequestURI()).build().getQueryParams();
    ...
```

I want to use:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(request.getRequestURI()).build().getQueryParams();
```

How does the new http look like?

How does the new @RequestMapping and method report() look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Spring annotations dont disallow arbitrary query params. It might restrict access to the endpoint based upon *missing parameters* which your endpoint requires. But will not restrict access to the endpoint for extra ones.

Based upon that method right now I could access it using this query `/report?name=test&download=false&myfoobar=21243hjof&blablablaba=beepboopbap`. Spring doesnt care that I added `myfoobar` and `blablablaba`.

To access everything just add the `HttpServletRequest` parameter to your method signature, order doesnt matter

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/report", params = {"name", "download"})
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> report(
    HttpServletRequest request,
    @RequestParam(value = "name") String name,
    @RequestParam(value = "download") boolean download) {
```

Then simply grab all your params using

```
request.getQueryString() // everything after ?, so its name=test&download=false&myfoobar=21243hjof&blablablaba=beepboopbap
```

Or you can use the request methods:

```
request.getParameter("myfoobar") // 21243hjof
```

or for your example you could do

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("?"+request.getQueryString()).build().getQueryParams();
```

---

Also you can use `@RequestParam Map<String,String> allRequestParams` to get all the parameters.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/report", params = {"name", "download"})
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> report(
    @RequestParam Map<String,String> allRequestParams,
    @RequestParam(value = "name") String name,
    @RequestParam(value = "download") boolean download) {
```